# Context Free Grammar for $L = \{0^n w 1^n \mid n \ge 0, w \in \{0, 1\}^*\}$

Tags: context-free-grammar

Title says it all. I'm trying to make sure I have the correct CFG for $L$ before I start converting it to GNF. I don't want to post my idea yet, as I don't want it to influence any of the replies.

Again, I need a CFG for

$$L = \left\{0^n w 1^n \mid n \ge 0, w \in \{0, 1\}^*\right\}$$

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don’t think that you need to worry about influencing the answers; a great many folks here would rather see that you’ve got somewhere with it yourself. This one’s easy enough that I’d normally just give a hint anyway, but I’ll say that you can do it with a grammar that has just the initial non-terminal and three productions, two of them terminal.

Comment: Would it simply be S -> 0S1 | 0 | 1  ?  That was one of my first ideas, but it didn't seem to quite fulfill the 0,1 esterate properly.  I mean, 0110101001101 wouldn't work in that CFG, even though it should.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: My other idea was S -> 0W1 / W -> 0W | 1W | S  That one seems to work so far, but I wanted to be sure before I started the long conversion process.

Comment: It is indeed just $S\to 0S1\mid 0\mid 1$. $0110101001101$ isn’t in $L$, so you don’t want to generate it!

Comment: I think that you’ve misunderstood what language $L$ is. The members of $L$ are the words of the form $$\underbrace{00\dots00}_nb\underbrace{11\dots11}_n$$ such that $n\ge 0$ and $b$ is either $0$ or $1$. It does not include, for instance, $01011$.

Comment: But it says that w is an element of 0,1 esterate, which means w could be any combination of 0s and 1s, isn't that right?  So, w could be an infinite amount of possible combinations of 0s and 1s.  This is what I learned the asterisk to mean when given an alphabet.  If it were just {0,1}, with no asterisk, then it would just be either 0 OR 1.

Comment: Sorry, you’re right: I missed the star. My apologies. At this point I might as well write up a quick answer.

Comment: Why is $L\ne\{0,1\}^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggested in comments on the basis of misreading the language can be easily modified to give a CFG that actually does generate $L$:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to 0S1\mid A\\
&A\to\epsilon\mid 0A\mid 1A
\end{align*}$$

The first production generates the surrounding $0^n\dots1^n$, and the $A$ then generates an arbitrary word over $\{0,1\}$ in the middle.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I was very close to this, but you made it wonderfully clear what I was doing wrong.  Thanks again.

Comment: @TheRationalist: You’re welcome, and I apologize for the initial confusion.

Comment: Just taking A at the first step shows that this language is equal to `{0,1}*`.

Comment: @It'sNotALie.: Indeed it does. But after seven years I’ve no idea why I didn’t bother to point that out at the time!

Answer (score 1):

That language is regular, it is in fact $\{0, 1\}^*$: you can always take $n = 0$ (no 0 at the beginning, no 1 at the end, anything whatsoever in between). So a grammar would be:

$\begin{equation*}
 S \to 0 S \mid 1 S \mid \varepsilon
\end{equation*}$